# Auto resize header with css only

Tags: html, css, header

I want to automatically resize the header using css but without using `repeat-x` - because the header contains picture and I don't want it to repeat when a user resizes the page (CTRL with +scroll ).

I tried `width: 100%;` but it did not work

Comment: like this with out repeat-x 

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mst5g/)

Comment: Is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183648/header-wrapper-re-size-css?

Comment: If you want to be able to ask questions, then you need to read [ask], and even [help] and maybe take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) style:

```
header {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ywypdrj7/)

Comment: thanks that's fixed the problem , now the wrappers went to left when i re-size i want the wrappers to stay in the middle same like header,

Comment: Can to reproduce your issue in a live demo?

Comment: yes sure look at home icon when u scroll down and change the size it goes to the left side i want it to be in the middle http://jsfiddle.net/6xaeej5f/

Comment: @HeqDz That's a different question altogether.

Comment: @HeqDz Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background-size: cover