# header wrapper re-size css

Tags: html, css

i waited for 7 days to ask this question because i can't ask more question,
i want to keep the wrapper in the middle when people re-size the page

```css
header {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#home {
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:400px;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <img id="home" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/snipicons/5000/home-128.png" alt="home" style="width:75px;height:67px">
</header>
```

thnx

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6xaeej5f/ this is example u can see the "home" wrapper in the header keep going to the left when i try to re-size the page i want it to stay in the midle thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add `text-align: center` to the parent element. The `img` will respect this because it is `inline` by default.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fz3c26h/)

```
header {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339) for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it, if all you need is keeping the icon centred all the time you don't really need to absolute position it.

```css
header {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#home {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: no problem, you should mark one as the correct answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#home {
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:48%;
}
```

Comment: thanks man it's does the same as the other solution !